# Does Set in Ruby always preserve insertion order?

Tags: ruby, set

i.e., is Ruby's Set equivalent to Java's LinkedHashSet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9: **yes**.  In Ruby 1.8: *probably not*.

`Set` [uses a `Hash` internally](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/set.rb#L222); and since hashes are insertion-ordered in 1.9, you're good to go!

As [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) points out, this is an implementation detail and could change in the future (though unlikely).  Thankfully, the current implementation of `Set` is pure ruby, and could be adapted into an `OrderedSet` in the future if you like

Comment: Sort of. [The documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) says "Set implements a collection of unordered values with no duplicates". The use of a Hash internally is an implementation detail that could change at any time and the "orderedness" is not guaranteed by the interface spec. OTOH, it also says that "Set uses Hash as storage." so...