# How do I figure out if I have already added an array of strings to my array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, duplicates

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I have an array of strings, which I want to add to an array of arrays.  So for example, if I have two arrays,

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["1", "2", "3"]
```

As I gradually add these arrays into my array of arrays, my resulting array of arrays will look like

```
[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]
```

I achieve this using the below

```
if data_cols.size == 0
  data_cols = parts
else
  if parts.size > data_cols.size
    num_elts = data_cols[0].size
    (0..(parts.size - data_cols.size)).each do |i|
      arr = Array.new(num_elts)
      data_cols.push(arr)  
    end
  end
  data_cols = data_cols.zip(parts).map(&:flatten) 
end
```

My question is, how do I figure out if I have already added an array of strings?  So for isntance, if I were adding

```
["a", "b", "c"]
["1", "2", "3"]
["a", "b", "c"]
```

The result would be

```
[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]
```

since I tried to add '["a", "b", "c"]' a second time.  Right now, the result is

```
[["a", "1", "a"], ["b", "2", "b"], ["c", "3", "c"]]
```

Comment: btw `["a", "b", "c"].zip ["1", "2", "3"] #=> [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]`

Comment: While it's possible to check to see what has been added, it's costly as the array grows. Arrays are great for things you want to process in order, but are terrible for finding things. Your question seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) where you might need to look for a different structure for storing your data.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I figure out if I have already added an array of strings?

Here we check if `check` has already been added to `array`:

```
check = ["a", "b", "c"]
array = [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]

array.transpose.include? check #=> true
```

*steps:*

```
a = array.transpose #=> [["a", "b", "c"], ["1", "2", "3"]]
a.include? check    #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set to keep unique rows :

```
require 'set'

rows = Set.new
rows << ["a", "b", "c"]
rows << ["1", "2", "3"]
rows << ["a", "b", "c"]

columns = rows.to_a.transpose
p columns
#=> [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]
```

Note that since Ruby 1.9, Set uses a Hash internally so the order is preserved (related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10361275/6419007)). With your version (2.4), the order will be preserved. It isn't guaranteed to work on any other Ruby implementation (e.g. Ruby 1.8, Rubinius or JRuby) though.

Comment: If I use the Set data structure, will the order in which I insert elements (other than dupicate elements) be preserved?

Comment: Yes it will for any CRuby since 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `zip` correctly. Here's a reworked, more minimal version:

```
data = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["1", "2", "3"],
  ["a", "b", "c"]
]

# Take first row of data as headers, group the rest together
headers, *rows = data

rows.map do |row|
  headers.zip(row)
end.to_a
# => [[["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]], [["a", "a"], ["b", "b"], ["c", "c"]]]
```

This combines two three-element arrays using `zip` and reworks each row to be in the right format.

If you're looking to exclude duplicates, you can always pre-process with:

```
data.uniq!
```

Do that before splitting out the headers and you won't have any duplicate entries, or if the headers are repeated they're ignored.

If you want to *only* exclude the headers from the data, then you can do this:

```
rows.delete(headers)
```

Sometimes when trying to solve simple problems like this it's easy to get tripped up in your own code, especially as you're going against the grain and fighting Ruby to get a solution. Things like `if data_cols.size == 0` and then initializing it is a sign you're over-complicating things, though sometimes those signs are easy to miss.

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep unique rows. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil Hm, I'll add another approach then.

Answer (score 0):

Just `uniq` your input in advance:

```
data.uniq.reduce(&:zip).map(&:flatten)
```